# insert record where not exist

Tags: oracle, insert, not-exists, ora-00001

```
INSERT INTO CUST_ID_HISTORY(CUST_ID,PREVIOUS_CUST_ID,UPDATE_DATE) 
SELECT CUST_ID,PREVIOUS_CUST_ID,UPDATE_DATE
FROM CUST_ID_HISTORY WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUST_ID_HISTORY WHERE
CUST_ID='SCB301' AND PREVIOUS_CUST_ID='SCB201');
```

Above query insert a new record to `CUST_ID_HISTORY` when inserted value is not exist in the table.I encounter error `ORA-00001: unique constraint` with the supplied value, but both values are not exist in the table.

Comment: Can you explain what above query is written to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement selects from CUST_ID_HISTORY and inserts into CUST_ID_HISTORY . In other words, when there is no record for where `CUST_ID != 'SCB301'` and `PREVIOUS_CUST_ID != 'SCB201'` it tries to create a duplicate record for *every record in CUST_ID_HISTORY*. Presumably this is the table's primary key, hence the ORA-00001 unique key violation.

If what you're trying to achieve is insert a record into CUST_ID_HISTORY for those values perhaps you need a merge statement. Something like this:

```
merge into CUST_ID_HISTORY tgt
using ( select 'SCB301' as id, 'SCB201' as prev_id
         from dual ) src
on ( src.id = tgt.cust_id 
      and src.prev_id = tgt.prev_cust_id)
when not matched then
    insert (cust_id, prev_cust_id, update_date)
    values (src.id, src.prev_id, sysdate)
/
```

Comment: It does not insert duplicate rows where `CUST_ID != 'SCB301' or PREVIOUS_CUST_ID != 'SCB201'` - If there is not a row where `CUST_ID = 'SCB301' AND PREVIOUS_CUST_ID = 'SCB201'` then it will duplicate all the rows otherwise it will insert zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
INSERT INTO CUST_ID_HISTORY(CUST_ID,PREVIOUS_CUST_ID,UPDATE_DATE) 
SELECT CUST_ID,PREVIOUS_CUST_ID,UPDATE_DATE
FROM CUST_ID_HISTORY
```

will duplicate **all** the rows of the `CUST_ID_HISTORY` table.

Adding the filter:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM CUST_ID_HISTORY
  WHERE CUST_ID='SCB301' AND PREVIOUS_CUST_ID='SCB201'
);
```

Will check whether there is an existing row in table with `CUST_ID='SCB301' AND PREVIOUS_CUST_ID='SCB201'` if the row does not exist then **all** the rows from the `CUST_ID_HISTORY` table will be duplicated and, if such a row exists then the statement will insert zero rows.

So your query will either duplicate **all** the rows or will do nothing.

If you want to insert a single new row, checking that it does not exist then:

```
INSERT INTO CUST_ID_HISTORY(CUST_ID,PREVIOUS_CUST_ID,UPDATE_DATE) 
SELECT 'SCB301',
       'SCB201',
       SYSDATE   -- The current date/time
FROM   DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM CUST_ID_HISTORY
  WHERE CUST_ID='SCB301' AND PREVIOUS_CUST_ID='SCB201'
);
```

or:

```
MERGE INTO CUST_ID_HISTORY dst
USING (
  SELECT 'SCB301' AS CUST_ID,
         'SCB201' AS PREVIOUS_CUST_ID
  FROM   DUAL
) src
ON (   src.CUST_ID          = dst.CUST_ID
   AND src.PREVIOUS_CUST_ID = dst.PREVIOUS_CUST_ID )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( CUST_ID, PREVIOUS_CUST_ID, UPDATE_DATE ) 
  VALUES ( src.CUST_ID, src.PREVIOUS_CUST_ID, SYSDATE );
```

Which will both check if there is an existing row and insert a single row if it does not exist.